# Can I take a subclass object from a vector of superclass objects and push it into a sublcass vector?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, subclass

I have two vectors of different classes, where `Slot`,`Field`, and `Vacuum` are subclasses of `Space`.

```
vector<Space *> av_spaces;
vector<Slot> av_slots;
vector<Field> av_fields;
vector<Vacuum> av_vacuums;
```

Here's what I am trying to do.

```
av_slots.push_back(av_spaces[i])
```

Now my program validates that `av_spaces[i]` is a `Slot` for sure, before trying to push it.

This is the error I am getting,
"No matching member function for call to 'push_back'".

Now I am not really sure why; I am assuming since I am trying to push a `Space` into a vector of `Slots` it's not technically matching the type of the vector it's being pushed into - but why can't it? If at the end of the day, a `Slot` is a `Space`. right?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are sure `av_spaces[i]` points to a `Slot`, then make it `av_slots.push_back(*static_cast<Slot*>(av_spaces[i]))`

Comment: A `Slot` is a `Space`, right. But a `Space*` is not a `Slot`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It compiled! I am trying to understand what's going on here: I am casting ```Space*``` into a ```Slot*``` and then getting the actual ```Slot``` right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will push a copy of the original object into the `av_slots` vector. Changes made to it or the original object won't be reflected in the other.